# iOS subscription payment

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a question about apple review system.

I have a website where user can subscribe to different plan through 3rd party (the subscription is linked to user’s account) to access to some content.

I have also an iOS application that not let user subscribe to this plan directly from the app (just an informative message to says user that subscription must be made from my website, and their is no redirection to my websites like spotify do it).

Is the application will be rejected because it’s not use In App Purchase ?

Thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use In App purchase for this purpose. If you don't, your app might get rejected with the following response from Apple.

*We noticed that your app contains a payment mechanism other than in-app purchase for digital content or to unlock features or functionality within your app, which is not appropriate for the App Store. In-app purchase is the only valid in-app payment mechanism for digital content.
Note: Continuing to hide functionality within your app or other dishonest acts may result in the removal of your apps from the App Store and termination of your Apple Developer Program membership and all associated memberships.
Next Steps
To resolve this issue, please remove all external or third-party payment mechanisms and implement in-app purchase to facilitate digital good transactions, including unlocking features or functionality within your app.
If you believe your use of an alternative payment mechanism is a permissible use case, please respond directly to this message in Resolution Center with detailed information.*

you may visit it for further information and guidelines.
https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Comment: The problem is : this subscription include a multilevel marketing with funds transfer between users and I think that In app purchase do not provide Api to transfer funds. Example : user A subscribe to 20$ subscription, the fund go to Stripe account. User A sponsored user B and at this moment we transfer 5$ to user A from stripe to his personnal bank account.

Comment: what do you mean by User A sponsors User B? Does it mean User A buys for User B and now User B is in app's pro mode?

Comment: No user A share his QR code to user B to join the program. User B subscribe to our plan. We give to user A 5$ (transfert is made from stripe to his personnal bank account)

Comment: Well in this case you can handle both the scenarios in different ways. For instance, for the product's plans you can use IAP. You would also need Backend server for keeping the records for all transactions so you know whom you want to send payment or not.
Once user B joins the program, you can ask the user A for his bank account number. From there, you can send the payment to user A using stripe or any other suitable payment method.
In summary you're using IAP for product purchase and for funds transfer you can use stripe with backend server for payments transfer. Hope it will help.